# Removing XSS Entries In Email Text Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have text that is saved to the database.This text is an email message formatted as an HTML string.
I am trying to parse the string so that I can remove attributes with the ON or JAVASCRIPT attributes. My problem is that using .HTML() seems to strip out the  and  tags from the returned string. How can I prevent these  and  tags from being deleted?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      function trimAttributes(node) {
           
            $.each(node.attributes, function () {

                var attrName = this.name;
                var attrValue = this.value;
             
                if (attrName.indexOf('on') == 0 || attrValue.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) {

                    $(node).removeAttr(attrName);
                }
            });
        }

        function sanitize(content) {
            if (content !== "undefined" && content !="") {

                var output = $($.parseHTML('<div>' + content + '</div>'));
              
                output.find('*').each(function () {
                    trimAttributes(this);
                });

                return output.html() ;
            }
        }


       
        </script>
```

example call:
document.CARS.benefits_text.value = sanitize(document.CARS.benefits_text.value);

Comment: Note that your current approach would not prevent all XSS techniques anyway. For example, say if I had an image tag with an `onload` / `onerror` event handler - this will probably run before you can remove the attribute. You should at least put the content into a [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) tag not a `<div>`.

Comment: Additionally, there's tags in there that you're not catching -- e.g. it doesn't matter what the attributes of a `<script>` tag are, you don't want it there all. Even the literal `<!--` is something you want to look out for.